# PHP Mysql update query returns nothing

Tags: php

Hi guys my php update query doesnt return me any value. It should return me `success` or `failed` but its not can you guys fix this?

> disregard securities here I just use this query for my android app.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['txtCar_No']) &&  isset($_POST['txtCarModel']) && 
    isset($_POST['txtCarType']) && isset($_POST['txtCapacity']) && 
    isset($_POST['image']) && isset($_POST['txtFuelType']) && 
    isset($_POST['txtPlateNumber']) &&  isset($_POST['txtcarPrice']))
{
    $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
    $id = $now->format('YmdHis');

    $upload_folder = "upload";
    $path = "$upload_folder/$id.jpeg";
    $fullpath = "http://carkila.esy.es/$path";

    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $Car_No = $_POST['txtCar_No'];
    $Car_Model = $_POST['txtCarModel'];
    $Car_Type = $_POST['txtCarType'];
    $Capacity = $_POST['txtCapacity'];
    $Fuel_Type = $_POST['txtFuelType'];
    $PlateNumber = $_POST['txtPlateNumber'];
    $carPrice = $_POST['carPrice'];

    $query = "UPDATE tbl_cars SET Car_Model='$Car_Model', Car_Type='$Car_Type', Capacity='$Capacity', fuelType='$Fuel_Type' ,carPlatenuNumber='$PlateNumber', image='$fullpath' , carPrice = '$carPrice' WHERE Car_No=$Car_No";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    echo $Car_No;

    if($result > 0){
        echo "success";   
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "failed";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131304/how-to-determine-if-a-mysql-update-query-succeeded-when-the-data-passed-in-the-q) Question. Since its related and handled before

Comment: you can use mysqli_error function and check error in your query. it shows any error in query

Comment: use mysqli_num_rows($result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `mysqli_affected_rows($conn)` to get rows affected by this update query.

E.g.:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$count = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);



if($result == TRUE && $count > 0){
    echo "success";   
    exit();
} else {   
    print_r (mysqli_error($conn));
    echo "failed";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value in `$return`  after `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);`?

For successful `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN` queries, `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result object`. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`. Returns `FALSE` on failure.

So the value of `$result` after your `UPDATE`-query can only be true or false, nothing else.

Your `echo..if...` can be simplified to one line:

```
echo ($result?"success":"failed");
```

Hope this helps.